# How to leave two decimal places after the comma,

Tags: r

Note that the values of my column `time` in the output table are rounded, but I would like to leave the values two decimal places after the comma, how to adjust this in the code below?

```
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date1 = as.Date(c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-01")),
                       date2 = as.Date(c("2021-10-22","2021-10-22","2021-10-28","2021-10-30")),
                       Week = c("Friday", "Friday", "Thursday", "thursday"),
                       Category = c("FDE", "FDE", "FDE", "FDE"),
                       time = c(4, 6, 6, 3)), class = "data.frame",row.names = c(NA, -4L))

Test<-Test %>%
  group_by(Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category) %>% 
  summarise(time = mean(time, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')

Test <- transform(Test, time = round(time))

> Test
      Week Category time
1   Friday      FDE    5
2 Thursday      FDE    4
```

Comment: You cannot have a numeric value such as `5.00` , `4.50` etc unless you transform to character.  `Test <- transform(Test, time = sprintf('%.2f', round(time, 2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Onyambu's suggestion is:

```
Test <- transform(Test, time = format(round(time, digits = 2), nsmall = 2))
```

The nsmall argument of format sets  the minimum number of digits to the right of the decimal.